# wget not working to download jar file from maven repo

Tags: java, maven, jar, wget, guava

I'm trying to download a single jar file from the maven repository, from the URL below.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava-testlib/10.0/guava-testlib-10.0.jar

- Downloading in a browser works fine, and I get the file as expected.
- 'wget' downloads something, but the file I get doesn't appear to be valid. Running 'jar -tf' on the downloaded file gives 'ZipException: error in opening zip file'.
- Downloading the file programmatically from Java ('InputStream' from the URL writing to a 'FileOutputStream') downloads something and creates the file. Opening that with WinZip/7-Zip, it appears to contain one file named 'guava-testlib-10.0', which looks like the jar archive I was expecting to get.
- `wget` another jar does work as expected at least sometimes (with `-U` user agent string)

Is this some dodgy interaction between wget/maven or Java/maven? Is it a malformed jar file that my browser understands and downloads correctly? Both of those seem slightly implausible to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

wget generally gets blocked from the central maven repo because some people don't play nice and try to wget too much.  Try set the user agent:

```
wget -U "Any User Agent" http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava-testlib/10.0/guava-testlib-10.0.jar
```

Comment: The user agent doesn't appear to make any difference. With or without, it downloads something, just not the right thing. Interestingly, it no longer lets me wget the sources jar without the user agent, so maybe this is something to do with it.

Comment: Without the user agent the return code is 403 (unauthorized).  Not sure why you still get a .jar :-/  Can you copy/paste the output of wget here?

Comment: Ok, today wget without a user agent does give a 403, and now the download works correctly if I use a user agent. I suppose the jar may have changed overnight?